# Dygraph: why does this data only show 1 line and not 2

Tags: dygraphs

Using dygraph (pretty awsome stuff) recentely.
When the data is like this I get only one line and not 2:

```
Tijd,SPO2,BPM
2014/09/14 21:01:31,99,76
2014/09/14 21:02:05,100,79
2014/09/14 21:02:48,99,80
2014/09/14 21:02:50,100,80
2014/09/14 21:02:54,99,81
2014/09/14 21:03:13,100,85
2014/09/14 21:03:22,99,82
```

Why?

Comment: Can you show the exact code you're using or set up a JSFiddle illustrating the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When I used your data in a simple test case using dygraphs, it does plot two lines.

[image: dygraphs example]

Here's the code I used:

```
var element = document.getElementById("graph");
var data = "Tijd,SPO2,BPM\n" +
           "2014/09/14 21:01:31,99,76\n" +
           "2014/09/14 21:02:05,100,79\n" +
           "2014/09/14 21:02:48,99,80\n" +
           "2014/09/14 21:02:50,100,80\n" +
           "2014/09/14 21:02:54,99,81\n" +
           "2014/09/14 21:03:13,100,85\n" +
           "2014/09/14 21:03:22,99,82\n";
var options = {
    legend: 'always',
    animatedZooms: true,
    title: 'Stack Overflow 25854175'
};

g = new Dygraph(element, data, options);
```

[Here's a working example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jstricker/a7434k71/) if you'd like to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I set the valueRange option and when setting only one valueRange option that means it draws only one line. Even when the cvs data indicates two lines.

So, problem fixed.

Thanks for a very nice library.

Kind regards,

Jeroen Baten

Comment: After I got the answer I could finish my project. The result is described in the following article: http://www.jeroenbaten.nl/cardio-oxygen-saturation-monitoring-home/. Thanks for an amazing library!